# How build a correct array structure for a Manu & Submenu?

Tags: php, arrays, navigation

I want to create this menu. It is an example with some sub menus.

- The Green - Nice Color
- The Sun - Hot Color
- The Sky - Freedom

  - Free
  - Free2

How can I create this the menu with sub menu example simplest?

I have created an array. It's the right way?

```
$NavMenu = [
       'The Green' => 
            [
              'name' => 'The Green',
              'subname' => 'Nice Color',
              'href' => 'greenlink',
              'title' => 'green is nature',
              'icon' => 'globe',
              'class' => 'green',
              'subnav' => ''
            ],
       'The Sun' => 
            [
              'name' => 'The Sun',
              'subname' => 'hot color',
              'href' => 'yellowlink',
              'title' => 'yellow is sun',
              'icon' => 'sunicon',
              'class' => 'yellow',
              'subnav' => ''
            ],
        'The Sky' => 
            [
              'name' => 'The Sky',
              'subname' => 'freedom',
              'href' => 'bluelink',
              'title' => 'blue is cold',
              'icon' => 'free',
              'class' => 'yellow',
              'subnav' =>  
                              [
                                'name' => 'Free',
                                'href' => 'bluelinkFree',
                                'title' => 'freedom is love',
                                'class' => 'blueFreedom'
                              ],
                              [
                                'name' => 'Free2',
                                'href' => 'bluelinkFree2',
                                'title' => 'freedom is love2',
                                'class' => 'blueFreedom2'
                              ]
            ]

    ];
```

is foreach the right way?

expect the output

```
<ul>
<li>
    <a class="green" href="greenlink" title="green is nature">
     <span icon="globe"></span>The Green - Nice Color</a>
</li>
<li>
    <a class="yellow" href="yellowlink" title="yellow is sun">
     <span icon="sunicon"></span>The Sun - hot color</a>
</li>
<li>
    <a class="blue" href="bluelink" title="blue is cold">
     <span icon="free"></span>The Sky - freedom</a>
     <ul>
         <li>
          <a class="blueFreedom" href="bluelinkFree" title="freedom is love">Free</a>
         </li>
<li>
          <a class="blueFreedom2" href="bluelinkFree2" title="freedom is2 love">Free2</a>
         </li>
     </ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This part of your array `'subnav' => 'Free' =` is not valid php.

Also note that there are array keys missing like `subname` and `icon` for the sub menu that you want to create.

You could use a single `foreach` and check if the key `subnav` key contains an array:

```
echo "<ul>";
foreach ($NavMenu as $navItem) {
    echo sprintf(
        '<li><a class="%s" href="%s" title="%s"><span icon="%s"></span>%s - %s</a>',
        $navItem["class"],
        $navItem["href"],
        $navItem["title"],
        $navItem["icon"],
        $navItem["name"],
        $navItem["subname"]
    );
    if (is_array($navItem["subnav"])) {
        $subNavItem = $navItem["subnav"];
        echo sprintf(
            '<ul><li><a class="%s" href="%s" title="%s"><span icon="%s"></span>%s - %s</a></li></ul>',
            $subNavItem["class"],
            $subNavItem["href"],
            $subNavItem["title"],
            $subNavItem["icon"],
            $subNavItem["name"],
            $subNavItem["subname"]
        );
    }
    echo "</li>";
}
echo "</ul>";
```

See a [Php demo](https://3v4l.org/COMqI)

Comment: Thanks, but how do I do that if I have more than 1 submenu?

Comment: @cemfirat Then you could use a second foreach. See https://3v4l.org/3WXOY